# Is there a way to give different sizes to a pyplot axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, grid, axis

i have been searching and can't find a way to create this graph on Python pyplot:
[Natural vaporization on aerial tanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6pJ5.jpg)

Any ideas how to start?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph looks like using straightforward log-log axes. The diagonal lines are of the form `y = f*x` with `f = 5,10,15,...`.

Here is some code to get you started:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter, NullFormatter
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xlim(0.1, 7)
ax.set_xticks([0.5] + [i for i in range(1, 8)])
ax.set_xticks([i / 10 for i in range(1, 20)], minor=True)
ax.set_ylim(1, 100)
ax.set_yticks([i for i in range(1, 10)] + [i for i in range(10, 101, 10)])
ax.set_yticks([i / 10 for i in range(10, 30)] + [i for i in range(10, 30)], minor=True)
ax.grid(axis='both', which='major', color='grey', lw=1)
ax.grid(axis='both', which='minor', color='grey', lw=.5)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%g'))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(NullFormatter())
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%g'))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(NullFormatter())

x = np.logspace(*np.log10([0.07, 7]), 200)
for f in [i for i in range(5, 50, 5)] + [i for i in range(50, 100, 10)]:
    ax.plot(x, f * x, color='crimson')

plt.show()
```

[image: log log grid]